# Is the inverse of the metric tensor also a tensor?

Tags: tensors, index-notation

In my textbook the inverse of the metric tensor ($g^{ij}$) is defined the following way:
$$g^{ij}g_{jk}=\delta^i_k$$
Then if we have the matrices forward and backward transforamtion $A$ and $B$, we know that the metric tensor transforms like:
$$g_{i'j'}=A^i_{\text{ } i'}A^j_{\text{ } j'}g_{ij}$$
How do we prove that the inverse of the metric also transforms like a tensor:
$$g^{i'j'}=B^{i'}_{\text{ }i}B^{j'}_j g^{ij}$$
I tried transforming the first equation but got nonsense.

Comment: Do you know the quotient theorem for tensors?

Comment: @user10354138 I'm not sure (English isn't the language I'm styding in). Isn't that just a contraction operation of a tensor product? If yes then how does the proof look then?

Comment: As $g_{ij}$ is nondegenerate, we have every covector $a$ comes from some vector $b$ by $a_i=g_{ij}b^j$.  Hence $g^{ij}a_j=g^{ij}g_{jk}b^k=\delta^i_k b^k=b^i$.  In other words, the contraction of $g^{ij}$ with arbitrary covector $a$ is a vector $b$, so $g^{ij}$ is a tensor by quotient theorem.